# Is Camera Calibration needed to get measurements from an image?

Tags: computer-vision, photogrammetry

I am working on an android application that measures distances (euclidean distances) from a digital image. I know that in order to get real world measures like cm or meters I have to use an object with a known dimensions. Is Camera Calibration needed to get measurements from an image if I am using an object as a reference?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to measure? Is it something on the reference object? Is it the reference object itself?

Comment: I am trying to measure the distance between the pupils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: No

Long:
Camera Calibration (parameters) are in terms of optimization an additional term (sometimes a polynom) which can improve the resulting accuracy.

Think about it as an regression: If you have enough data to fit an higher order polynomial with a better insample/outsample error then you should should use the additional parameter(s). If you don't have enough data then you overfit and the insample/outsample error will be worse.

Especially in photogrammetry camera calibration parameters **need** to have a certain angle and camera position or combinations of them (relative to the object which you measure). Otherwise you wont be able to calculate the parameter with an significant value.

Answer (score 2):

Antonio Criminisi's PhD thesis contains all the basics on this issue.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398387/measuring-an-object-from-a-picture-using-a-known-object-size/11412722#11412722) to a related question.

Comment: thanks :), I'm reading the paper that you recommend in that answer

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it - helps with reputation building.