# Detect edges of barcode with OpenCV in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, barcode

I'm having the user capture an image of a barcode that they are asked to place inside a bounding box drawn on the camera overlay.  I'd like to detect whether that barcode was properly placed in the box.  What would be the best way to detect this?  OpenCV's houghLines? And how would I figure out if the lines detected from houghLines are the barcode's corner and that they match up with the camera overlay's bounding box?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post [How to find corners on a Image using OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263621/how-to-find-corners-on-a-image-using-opencv) has the solution for your problem. I did the same for my project and it worked like a charm :) If need help in understanding or tuning the algorithm, don't hesitate.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Do you think doing a median blur, canny edge detection and then a harris corner detection would do the trick?

Comment: That could be a possible pre-processing for the image, yes. I actually use Gaussian blur or Bilateral filter for smoothing, and instead of canny I use Sobel. It's a matter of testing out different combinations of filters and see which one works best for you :)