# How do I get the vertices from an edge image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have just used canny edge detection to detect a rectangle in an image. I would like to get the four corners of the rectangle

Comment: Please see my answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263621/how-to-find-corners-on-a-image-using-opencv/7263794#7263794][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263621/how-to-find-corners-on-a-image-using-opencv/7263794#7263794

Comment: @Throwback1986 Can you please explain step 7. I do not fully understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer here: [How to find corners on a Image using OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263621/how-to-find-corners-on-a-image-using-opencv/7263794#7263794)

As for step 7: cvApproxPoly returns a CvSeq*.  [This link](http://www.aishack.in/2010/01/an-introduction-to-contours/) explains it well.  As shown [here](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/core_2include_2opencv2_2core_2types__c_8h_source.html), a CvSeq struct contains a *total* member that contains the number of elements in the sequence.  In the case of a true quadrilateral, *total* should equal 4. If the quadrilateral is a square (or rectangle), angles between adjacent vertices should be ~90 degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a question. I am using c++ to perform this operation.What is the equivalent way of finding the CVseq result in c++.How do I  get that value from approxPolyDp();

Answer (score 0):

[findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) will give you the outline points

Comment: I am trying to find the corners of the rectangle.

Comment: [apprxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#void%20approxPolyDP(InputArray%20curve,%20OutputArray%20approxCurve,%20double%20epsilon,%20bool%20closed)) with a high value for epsilon should reduce it to a rect