# I have an image with rectangles in it, how to find bounding coordinates of the 4 corners. How to recognize each rectangle/square and find its coords?

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, geometry, image-recognition

I am trying to find the coordinates of coloured squares on a black background, created by children using paint. the images are in png format and want the coordinates for each corner. request anyone with image recognition or image processing skills to guide me as to how do i do it?

Comment: Please consider adding some code, otherwise this question is to broad. Please read through [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) carefully and specify your question.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I will do the needful and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Simon Fink the question is not complete. 
However, you can have a look at the following links for the solution.

[How to find corners on a Image using OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263621/how-to-find-corners-on-a-image-using-opencv)
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/