# Detect the location of a colored rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have a series of raw HD images at a resolution of 1920x1080px. These series of images may or may not contain one or more colored rectangles. Using some C++ code, I'd like to process the decoded RGBA images
to locate these rectangles (if they exist).

Instead of writing something from first principles, I was wondering if there was an existing framework I could use to detect/report the location (x/y coordinates) of the shapes within a given image. Is a library like OpenCv capable?

Criteria are as follows:

- Framework that will work with C/C++
- Performance is key - doing this real-time would be advantageous (say @ 50fps)
- The color of the rectangles would be known before the run. I have *no* experience with computer vision, but doing a web search, I see lots of posts requiring training sets - I don't want that.
- Detecting only rectangles for now is fine, but it would be great to be able to expand this to say circles but I want to start simple.
- The images to-be-searched may contain lots of noise, but the colour of the shape will be unique.

Attached is a simplified example image (without much noise) containing a green rectangle; I'd like detect the x/y coordinate of the green rectangle.

Any tips/suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image: Example of an image to be searched]

Comment: I recommend posting to [softwarerecs.se], since asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I do recommend writing it from scratch. Since the color is known, you can easily obtain the mask, do some [morphological operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphological-dilation-and-erosion.html) to remove noise and get the bounding box. You can get say 200 FPS. No training required, this is not a machine learning task.

Comment: I do agree with Burak,  Since the colour seems to be unique you could go for a colour "filter"  here : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html  convert it to black and white (speedup) only marking your region of interest and apply edge detection with optional bounding rectangle for your coordinates of your marked polygon

Answer (score 0):

I can at least give u a hint

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int w = 100;
    int h = 100;

    int screen_w = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
    int screen_h = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, screen_w, screen_h);
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HGDIOBJ oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, w, h, hdc, x, y, CAPTUREBLT | SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER infohdr = { sizeof(infohdr), w, h, 1, 32 };
    int size = w * h * 4;
    std::vector<BYTE> bits(size);
    int res = GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, h, &bits[0],
        (BITMAPINFO*)&infohdr, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    if (res != h)
    {
        std::cout << "error\n";
        return 0;
    }

    BYTE* ptr = bits.data();
    //for(y = 0; y < h; y++)
    for (y = h - 1; y >= 0; y--) //bitmaps bits start from bottom, not top
    {
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            BYTE blu = ptr[0];
            BYTE grn = ptr[1];
            BYTE red = ptr[2];
            ptr += 4;
        }
    }

    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
    DeleteDC(memdc);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a Screenregion Pixelscan Code
The following link is a repos to a cursor position color detection project I've implemented with it. When u understand the code and your problem you could be able to take it on your own :)
https://github.com/Rick-laboratory/Windows-CursorPosition-ColorDetection/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263621/how-to-find-corners-on-a-image-using-opencv/7263794#7263794

The referenced OpenCV tutorial almost solves the problem out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I learned something.

Comment: @Throwback1986 what is the performance like?

Comment: Scanning is as performant as ur system can get because this approach takes one shot only, but when u want to take a series of shots to analyze. I would suggest working with DirectX on windows. I did not use OpenCV yet.